# express-session req.user is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, passport.js

I'm trying to use express session to login users. I'd like users to be able to go to a profile page and view their user data if they have logged in.

I've been stuck here for days. On line 33 of my `routes.js` file, in my `/profile GET` route, `req.user` is undefined. But on line 27 of my `routes.js`, in my `/login POST`, req.user works as it should.

```
'use strict'

var User = require('mongoose').model('User')

module.exports = function(app, passport){ 
    console.log('passport', passport)
    app.route('/')
        .get(function(req, res){
            res.render('index')
        })
    app.get('/signUp', function(req, res){
        res.render('signup')
    })

    app.route('/user')
        .get(function(req, res){
        })
        .post(passport.authenticate('local-signup', { successRedirect: '/',
                                                        failureRedirect: 'signup' }))

    app.route('/login')
        .get(function(req, res){
            res.render('login')
        })
        .post(passport.authenticate('local-login', { successRedirect: '/',
                                                    failureRedirect: '/login'}), function(req, res){
                        /* *** LINE 27 ***  */  console.log('req.user', req.user)   
                                                    })

    app.route('/profile')
        .get(function(req, res){

   /* *** LINE 33 ***  */   console.log('req.user', req.user)

            if(!req.user){
                res.render('profile', {user: "You're not logged in"})
            }   
            if(req.user){
                res.render('profile', {user: req.user})
            }
        })
}
```

Why isn't `req.user` defined in all my routes? Shouldn't express session populate a persisting `req.user` object?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should define isLoginedIn funtion in routes.js as follow:

```
 // route middleware to ensure user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Then replace:

```
   app.route('/profile')
        .get(function(req, res){

            console.log('req.user', req.user)

            if(!req.user){
                res.render('profile', {user: "You're not logged in"})
            }   
            if(req.user){
                res.render('profile', {user: req.user})
            }
        })
```

by:

```
 // PROFILE SECTION =========================
    app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('profile.ejs', {
            user : req.user
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

In isLoggedIn req.isAuthenticated is returning false and thus this profile feature/route isn't working.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6c0b267a75cc3dcfc682#file-routes-js-L9