# passport req.isAuthenticated() always returns fasle

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, passport.js

I'm trying to use express session to login users. I'd like users to be able to go to a profile page and view their user data if they have logged in.

On line 9 of my routes.js: req.isAuthenticate() is returning false even though I've already successfully signed in a user.

My ultimate goal is for req.user, that passport saves to the session, to be defined in the /passport GET route so I can send it as data to my templeting engine.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f6ecb472eb082775181e#file-routes-js-L9

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it undefined or returning true? 
do you have `app.use(passport.initialize());`?

Comment: Once console.log(req.user); in the routes.

Comment: @KethaKavya If i console.log(req.user) in routes it works as expected in my  GET /login route but in my GET /profile route its undefined, even if I already successfully logging in the user. 
see my other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477443/express-session-req-user-is-undefined

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ Sorry, typo, req.isAuthenticate() is returning false. 
Yes i have app.use(passport.initialize()) on line 33 for express.js file https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f6ecb472eb082775181e#file-express-js-L33

Comment: Are you using https or http? Can you check to see if you already have a cookie on the browser after login?

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ I don't think I've specified, so I imagine http by default.

How can I check if I have a cookie in the browser after login?

Comment: @Casey I posted my answer. But please update your question and put some important parts of your code in there for future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is something wrong with your serialization/deserialization.

On serialization, you need to specify how you are going to serialize the user. According to your code you are using the users' ids to serialize them. And this is what is going to be used for deserialization. So, you should expect just an ID from the input parameters, and you have to find the user linked to that ID and pass it to the callback.

This would be what you should do:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
  User.findById(id, function(err, user){
    done(err, user)
  })
})
```